# Copying Multiple Items / Sections in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

When creating or editing a form, how can you copy multiple items/sections?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

First, if you are trying to capture the same information multiple times, you can use a Repeating Section, which is a section that the user filling out the form can repeat as necessary to enter the same information for a list of items, like players on a baseball team, employment history, medical conditions, etc.

[image: Example of Repeating Sections]

Second, while you can only copy one thing at a time, you can place a number of items (including both fields and other sections) into a section, and then copy and paste the entire section and all of the items contained in the section will be copied as well.